# Xamarin cannot sign into apple developer account

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am having an issue where when I attempt to sign into my **apple developer account.**
I go to *tools* > *options* > *xamarin* > *apple* *accounts*. I click on add accounts and enter the details but **I get the following error:**

```
There was an error trying to log in: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.
```

**Has anyone encountered this issue before?** How can I check the hostname its trying to resolve?
I'm running the latest version of visual studio on windows (15.9.17)

**Thanks**

Comment: You could update the IDE to VS 2019 (16.4.0) .

Comment: Also experiencing this visual studio 2017.